# CSS image and caption – height 100% together

Tags: html, css

I have a situation where an image needs to be displayed with a caption underneath (not overlapping). Neither the size of the image nor the length of the caption are known.

The height of the whole figure element needs to be 100% like this:

[image: Illustration]

The width of the element should be dynamic, determined by the image ratio, the caption should line break accordingly. This is important because I need to display several images next to each other.

Is there any way I can achieve this with just CSS?

I tried with CSS-tables, but that doesn't work with 100% height. You can see my effort here:

```
display: table
```

http://codepen.io/pju/pen/ZOmdEb

And with flexbox, which has its own problems.

```
display: flex
```

http://codepen.io/pju/pen/QEJXNZ

Comment: with old/plain css, not really possible. newer css allows sizing "math" to be performed, but support isn't exactly universal yet. you'd properly need javascript to calculate sizing and set the styles accordingly there.

Comment: Their sum needs to be 100% of what? And, more importantly, what do you want to happen when their sum is bigger/smaller than the desired `100%`? Shrink/crop the image or rather just add some space between the image and the caption? The desired outcome is not entirely clear.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu 100% height of the container element …
And the image should shrink while keeping ratio. The space between caption and image should stay the same.

Comment: So you want each image+caption group to resize its width so the sum of their heights plus a certain fixed gap is the same (and probably set by the highest group and probably not larger than the viewport height). If this is correct, it's not possible with CSS alone, afaik. You need DOM manipulation (JavaScript, TypeScript, jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

I know that using a `<video>` element for purposes other than presenting video is very unsemantic, but it's strange that the element's attribute `poster` enables it to handle an image better than an `<img>`. You weren't clear as to the dimensions of the actual wrapper with it's relation to it's environment (i.e. body, viewport, or another wrapper perhaps?).

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #000;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.box {
  display: table;
}
.frame {
  width: -moz-max-content;
  width: -webkit-max-content;
  width: max-content;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table-row;
}
.image {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.title {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-variant: small-caps;
  line-height: 1.15;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(221, 126, 110, .2);
  color: #EFEFEF;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet'>
<section class='box'>
  <figure class='frame'>
    <video class='image' poster='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png'></video>
    <figcaption class='title'>Lena Söderberg 1972</figcaption>
  </figure>
</section>
```